# Custom session handler class - is it robust enough?

Tags: php, security, session

I've been working on this class for a while now and would appreciate some feedback, even if it's just nitpicking. I've added basic instructions on how to use the class below along with some questions.

```
<?php
/**
 * @category    Security
 * @version     1.0
 * @author      First Last <email@mail.com>
 * */
class SessionHandler
{
    /**
     * @description PDO database handle
     * @access private
     * @var PDO database resource
     * */
    private $_db                        = NULL;

    /**
     * @description Database table name where sessions are stored.
     * @access private
     * @var string
     * */
    private $_table_name                = 'sessions';

    /**
     * @description Cookie name where the session ID is stored.
     * @access private
     * @var string
     * */
    private $_cookie_name               = 'session_cookie';

    /**
     * @description Number of seconds before the session expires. Default is 2 hours.
     * @access private
     * @var integer
     * */
    private $_seconds_till_expiration   = 7200; // 2 hours

    /**
     * @description Number of seconds before the session ID is regenerated. Default is 5 minutes.
     * @access private
     * @var integer
     * */
    private $_renewal_time              = 300; // 5 minutes

    /**
     * @description Closes the session when the browser is closed.
     * @access private
     * @var boolean
     * */
    private $_expire_on_close           = FALSE;

    /**
     * @description IP address that will be checked against the database if enabled. Must be a valid IP address.
     * @access private
     * @var string
     * */
    private $_ip_address                = FALSE;

    /**
     * @description User agent that will be checked against the database if enabled.
     * @access private
     * @var string
     * */
    private $_user_agent                = FALSE;

    /**
     * @description Will only set the session cookie if a secure HTTPS connection is being used.
     * @access private
     * @var boolean
     * */
    private $_secure_cookie             = FALSE;

    /**
     * @description A hashed string which is the ID of the session.
     * @access private
     * @var string
     * */
    private $_session_id                = '';

    /**
     * @description Data stored by the user.
     * @access private
     * @var array
     * */
    private $_data                      = array();

    /**
     * @description Initializes the session handler.
     * @access public
     * @param array - configuration options
     * @return void
     * */
    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        // Sets user configuration
        $this->_setConfig($config);

        // Runs the session mechanism
        if ($this->_read()) {
            $this->_update();
        } else {
            $this->_create();
        }

        // Cleans expired sessions if necessary and writes cookie
        $this->_cleanExpired();
        $this->_setCookie();
    }

    /**
     * @description Regenerates a new session ID for the current session.
     * @access public
     * @return void
     * */
    public function regenerateId()
    {
        // Acquires a new session ID
        $old_session_id     = $this->_session_id;
        $this->_session_id  = $this->_generateId();

        // Updates session ID in the database
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE {$this->_table_name} SET time_updated = ?, session_id = ? WHERE session_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array(time(), $this->_session_id, $old_session_id));

        // Updates cookie
        $this->_setCookie();
    }

    /**
     * @description Sets a specific item to the session data array.
     * @access public
     * @param string - session data array key
     * @param string - data value
     * @return void
     * */
    public function setData($key, $value)
    {
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
        $this->_write(); // Writes to database
    }

    /**
     * @description Unsets a specific item from the session data array.
     * @access public
     * @param string - session data array key
     * @return void
     * */
    public function unsetData($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->_data[$key])) unset($this->_data[$key]);
    }

    /**
     * @description Returns a specific item from the session data array.
     * @access public
     * @param string - session data array key
     * @return string - data value/FALSE
     * */
    public function getData($key)
    {
        return isset($this->_data[$key]) ? $this->_data[$key] : FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * @description Returns all items in the session data array.
     * @access public
     * @return array
     * */
    public function getAllData()
    {
        return $this->_data;
    }

    /**
     * @description Destroys the current session.
     * @access public
     * @return void
     * */
    public function destroy()
    {
        // Deletes session from the database
        if (isset($this->_session_id))
        {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("DELETE FROM {$this->_table_name} WHERE session_id = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($this->_session_id));
        }

        // Kills the cookie
        setcookie(
            $this->_cookie_name,
            '',
            time() - 31500000,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
    }

    /**
     * @description The main session mechanism:
     *      - Reads session cookie and retrives session data
     *      - Checks session expiration
     *      - Verifies IP address (if enabled)
     *      - Verifies user agent (if enabled)
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _read()
    {
        // Fetches session cookie
        $session_id = isset($_COOKIE[$this->_cookie_name]) ? $_COOKIE[$this->_cookie_name] : FALSE;

        // Cookie doesn't exist!
        if (! $session_id) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->_session_id = $session_id;

        // Fetches the session from the database
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT data, time_updated, user_agent, ip_address FROM {$this->_table_name} WHERE session_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($this->_session_id));

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Did a session exist?
        if ($result !== FALSE && count($result) > 0)
        {
            // Checks if the session has expired in the database
            if (! $this->_expire_on_close)
            {
                if (($result['time_updated'] + $this->_seconds_till_expiration) < time())
                {
                    $this->destroy();
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            // Checks if the user's IP address matches the one saved in the database
            if ($this->_ip_address)
            {
                if ($result['ip_address'] != $this->_ip_address)
                {
                    $this->_flagForUpdate();
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            // Checks if the user's user agent matches the one saved in the database
            if ($this->_user_agent)
            {
                if ($result['user_agent'] != $this->_user_agent)
                {
                    $this->_flagForUpdate();
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            // Checks if the session has been requested to regenerate a new ID (hack attempt)
            $this->_checkUpdateFlag();

            // Checks if the session ID needs to be renewed (time exceeded)
            $this->_checkIdRenewal();

            // Sets user data
            $user_data = unserialize($result['data']);

            if ($user_data) {
                $this->_data = $user_data;
                unset($user_data);
            }

            // All good!
            return TRUE;
        }

        // No session found
        return FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * @description Creates a session.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _create()
    {
        // Generates session ID
        $this->_session_id = $this->_generateId();

        // Inserts session into database
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO {$this->_table_name} (session_id, user_agent, ip_address, time_updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($this->_session_id, $this->_user_agent, $this->_ip_address, time()));
    }

    /**
     * @description Updates a current session.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _update()
    {
        // Updates session in database
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE {$this->_table_name} SET time_updated = ? WHERE session_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array(time(), $this->_session_id));
    }

    /**
     * @description Writes session data to the database.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _write()
    {
        // Custom data doesn't exist
        if (count($this->_data) == 0) {
            $custom_data = '';
        } else {
            $custom_data = serialize($this->_data);
        }

        // Writes session data to database
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE {$this->_table_name} SET data = ?, time_updated = ? WHERE session_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($custom_data, time(), $this->_session_id));
    }

    /**
     * @description Sets session cookie.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _setCookie()
    {
        setcookie(
            $this->_cookie_name,
            $this->_session_id,
            ($this->_expire_on_close) ? 0 : time() + $this->_seconds_till_expiration, // Expiration timestamp
            NULL,
            NULL,
            $this->_secure_cookie, // Will cookie be set without HTTPS?
            TRUE // HttpOnly
        );
    }

    /**
     * @description Removes expired sessions from the database.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _cleanExpired()
    {
        // 0.1 % chance to clean the database of expired sessions
        if (mt_rand(1, 1000) == 1)
        {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("DELETE FROM {$this->_table_name} WHERE (time_updated + {$this->_seconds_till_expiration}) < ?");
            $stmt->execute(array(time()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @description Creates a unique session ID.
     * @access private
     * @return string
     * */
    private function _generateId()
    {
        $salt                   = 'x7^!bo3p,.$$!$6[&Q.#,//@i"%[X';
        $random_number          = mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        $ip_address_fragment    = md5(substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 5));
        $timestamp              = md5(microtime(TRUE) . time());

        $hash_data = $random_number . $ip_address_fragment . $salt . $timestamp;
        $hash = hash('sha256', $hash_data);

        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * @description Checks if the session ID needs to be regenerated and does so if necessary.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _checkIdRenewal()
    {
        // Gets the last time the session was updated
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT time_updated FROM {$this->_table_name} WHERE session_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($this->_session_id));

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($result !== FALSE && count($result) > 0)
        {
            // Checks if the session ID has exceeded it's permitted lifespan.
            if ((time() - $this->_renewal_time) > $result['time_updated'])
            {
                // Regenerates a new session ID
                $this->regenerateId();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @description Flags a session so that it will receive a new ID on the next subsequent request.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _flagForUpdate()
    {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE {$this->_table_name} SET flagged_for_update = '1' WHERE session_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($this->_session_id));
    }

    /**
     * @description Checks if the session has been requested to regenerate a new ID and does so if necessary.
     * @access private
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _checkUpdateFlag()
    {
        // Gets flagged status
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT flagged_for_update FROM {$this->_table_name} WHERE session_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($this->_session_id));

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($result !== FALSE && count($result) > 0)
        {
            // Flagged?
            if ($result['flagged_for_update'])
            {
                // Creates a new session ID
                $this->regenerateId();

                // Updates database
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE {$this->_table_name} SET flagged_for_update = '0' WHERE session_id = ?");
                $stmt->execute(array($this->_session_id));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @description Sets configuration.
     * @access private
     * @param array - configuration options
     * @return void
     * */
    private function _setConfig(array $config)
    {
        // Sets database handle
        if (isset($config['database'])) {
            $this->_db = $config['database'];
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Database handle not set!');
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // Cookie name
        if (isset($config['cookie_name']))
        {
            // Checks if alpha-numeric
            if (! ctype_alnum(str_replace(array('-', '_'), '', $config['cookie_name']))) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid cookie name!');
            }

            $this->_cookie_name = $config['cookie_name'];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // Database table name
        if (isset($config['table_name']))
        {
            // Checks if alpha-numeric
            if (! ctype_alnum(str_replace(array('-', '_'), '', $config['table_name']))) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid table name!');
            }

            $this->_table_name = $config['table_name'];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // Expiration time in seconds
        if (isset($config['seconds_till_expiration']))
        {
            // Anything else than digits?
            if (! is_int($config['seconds_till_expiration']) || ! preg_match('#[0-9]#', $config['seconds_till_expiration'])) {
                throw new Exception('Seconds till expiration must be a valid number.');
            }

            // Negative number or zero?
            if ($config['seconds_till_expiration'] < 1) {
                throw new Exception('Seconds till expiration can not be zero or less. Enable session expiration when the browser closes instead.');
            }

            $this->_seconds_till_expiration = (int) $config['seconds_till_expiration'];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // End the session when the browser is closed?
        if (isset($config['expire_on_close']))
        {
            // Not TRUE or FALSE?
            if (! is_bool($config['expire_on_close'])) {
                throw new Exception('Expire on close must be either TRUE or FALSE.');
            }

            $this->_expire_on_close = $config['expire_on_close'];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // How often should the session be renewed?
        if (isset($config['renewal_time']))
        {
            // Anything else than digits?
            if (! is_int($config['renewal_time']) || ! preg_match('#[0-9]#', $config['renewal_time'])) {
                throw new Exception('Session renewal time must be a valid number.');
            }

            // Negative number or zero?
            if ($config['renewal_time'] < 1) {
                throw new Exception('Session renewal time can not be zero or less.');
            }

            $this->_renewal_time = (int) $config['renewal_time'];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // Check IP addresses?
        if (isset($config['check_ip_address']))
        {
            // Not a string?
            if (! is_string($config['check_ip_address'])) {
                throw new Exception('The IP address must be a string similar to this: \'172.16.254.1\'.');
            }

            // Invalid IP?
            if (! preg_match('/^(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/', $config['check_ip_address'])) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid IP address.');
            }

            $this->_ip_address = $config['check_ip_address'];
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // Check user agent?
        if (isset($config['check_user_agent'])) {
            $this->_user_agent = substr($config['check_user_agent'], 0, 999);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------

        // Send cookie only when HTTPS is enabled?
        if (isset($config['secure_cookie']))
        {
            if (! is_bool($config['secure_cookie'])) {
                throw new Exception('The secure cookie option must be either TRUE or FALSE.');
            }

            $this->_secure_cookie = $config['secure_cookie'];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you would use the class. Notice how I have commented out the configuration options, this is because these are all set internally by default to give me a cleaner outside injection of configs so that I can omit them. I also inject the IP/UA so that it can be acquired in a proper manner which is not the job of the session class.

```
<?php

// Database connection
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=security', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Loads session handler
include_once('classes/session-class.php');

// SESSION HANDLER CONFIGRATION
$config['database']                 = $pdo;             // PDO Database handle

/*
$config['cookie_name']              = 'session_cookie'; // Name of the cookie
$config['table_name']               = 'sessions';       // Database table name
$config['seconds_till_expiration']  = 7200;             // How many seconds it takes before the session expires. Default is 2 hours.
$config['renewal_time']             = 300;              // How many seconds it takes before the session ID is renewed. Default is 5 minutes.
$config['expire_on_close']          = FALSE;            // The session is terminated when the browser is closed.
$config['secure_cookie']            = FALSE;            // Decides whether the cookie should only be set when a HTTPS connection exists.
$config['check_ip_address']         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];        // Will check the user's IP address against the one stored in the database. Make sure this is a string which is a valid IP address. FALSE by default.
$config['check_user_agent']         = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    // Will check the user's user agent against the one stored in the database. FALSE by default.
*/

try
{
    $session = new SessionHandler($config);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I improve the existing code?
2. Any obvious security or logic flaws?
3. Documented/commented well enough or too extensively?
4. For variables that are strings that will get set: use `FALSE` or `NULL` as default value? (e.g. `$_user_agent = FALSE` vs `NULL;`)
5. A better way to check for valid integers?
6. The `_setConfig()` method. Nasty or not? Is splitting it into smaller methods pointless?
7. Is there any benefit of commenting class variables?
8. `@param void` and `@return void` unnecessary?
9. Is it safe to omit single quotes for values in a database query with prepared statements? `?` vs `'?'`.

Comment: This question has a lot of views, so I'm assuming people are using your code. Would you mind posting your completed class in an edit?

Comment: I haven't looked at this code in years and would recommend anyone planning to use it to read through it carefully before doing so. I quit this project in favor of starting a more modular and unit tested one, but from reading that one I couldn't verify if it was any more stable than this production wise as I left php shortly after, so I decided not to post it. The code here might work as expected, but I would not advise anyone to use this untested code. Do not take the code here as an example of good coding, but as a learning reference.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looked like you may have been prepping this to release it publicly, which is why I asked.

Comment: Your code is near to perfect !

Comment: @n01ze I disagree. This class is nothing but a facade for database operations and thus send them all individually instead of as a transaction (where would be possible). It also has way too many responsibilities and was for that reason a pain to debug (yes, I still remember!). To top it off, this lead to subtle, yet dangerous bugs that could compromise the whole security of the session mechanism altogether (yes, I remember this too, it was that bad!). As I mentioned above; learning reference only, don't take this as an example of good code.

Comment: @Seralize Yep may be you are right , but the way you utilize all oop concept , DI etc are really commendable.And I liked the Doc Block too, its clear and very descriptive.Any ways Here you are just playing with Cookies, according to me it would be much better to manipulate SESSION from php's session handler interface or just function.Your class gave a idea , based on that I am gonna write a Session handling class that takes Session interface handlers into account.Thanks mate , Good Day

Comment: @Seralize check my class that overwrite  php default session handlers http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100448/simple-php-session-handler-class

Comment: What exactly is the point of `@access private` when the method clearly states that it is private?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks very good.  I like the way you are using Dependency Injection.  This code is a good example for other people to follow.

Here are just a few points, seeing as no-one else has answered.

> **1. How can I improve the existing code?**

Move the work that you do while constructing the object out of the constructor.  Miško Hevery says it better than i could [here.](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)  Basically it makes it harder for you to test or extend the object.  What I would do is replace your constructor with your setConfig method code as it is checking the configuration of the object you are creating (which is a good thing to do while constructing your object).

I would rewrite it with all of the checks and exceptions thrown first and then an assignment of all the fields done at the end of the constructor.

I would move the following from the constructor:

```
// Runs the session mechanism
if ($this->_read()) {
    $this->_update();
} else {
    $this->_create();
}
```

and make it a public method which would be called after the object was constructed.  I'm not sure what you would call it.  To me it looks like the whole thing could be named `update` because it updates or creates the session.

I would also move the cleanExpired and setCookie out of the constructor.  I'm not sure that cleanExpired really belongs with this class.  At least with it as a separate method you would have more control over the time at which it was called.

---

Very minor: Consider arranging the methods alphabetically within the class.

Very minor: I think 1 `if` statement is better than 2, consider changing the following:

```
    if (! $this->_expire_on_close)
    {
        if (($result['time_updated'] + $this->_seconds_till_expiration) < time())
```

to:

```
   if (! $this->_expire_on_close &&
       (($result['time_updated'] + $this->_seconds_till_expiration) < time()))
```

the logic is grouped together and is very readable.

> **2. Any obvious security or logic flaws?**

No obvious ones that I can see, but I didn't look very hard and am not a security expert.  I'd recommend checking out the password salting answers on stack overflow for specific advice on that.

> **3. Documented/commented well enough or too extensively?**

Looks good, it is nice to see the docblock comments.

> **4. For variables that are strings that will get set: use FALSE or NULL as default value? (e.g. $_user_agent = FALSE vs NULL;)**

My preference is for NULL.  It makes the check seem more natural:

```
   if (isset($_user_agent) &&
   // vs the more magical / less self explanatory.
   if (($_user_agent) &&
```

> **5. A better way to check for valid integers?**

I have heard that the [PHP filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) are good for this sort of thing.

> **6. The _setConfig() method. Nasty or not? Is splitting it into smaller methods pointless?**

See 1. I wouldn't split it up.

> **7. Is there any benefit of commenting class variables?**

Up to you.  Is @access needed? I thought that was generated automatically?

> **8. @param void and @return void unnecessary?**

Yes, I think they are unnecessary.

> **9. Is it safe to omit single quotes for values in a database query with prepared statements? ? vs '?'.**

Yes, the ? is a placeholder, trying to use '?' would make it a value and the query would no longer work (I think).

Comment: I've modified the class ever so slightly since posting the review and funnily enough I had already changed it in most ways as suggested.

Comment: how do i store and echo session values. a small documentation would be helpful i tried `<?php
        include_once('classes/session-class.php');
        session_start();
        $session = new mySessionHandler($config);
        // put your code here
        echo $config['cookie_name'];
        ?>` this doesn't work

Comment: You would need to look at the public methods of the class `SessionHandler` (not `mySessionHandler`).  It looks like the `setData` and `getData` methods could help.

Comment: @Paul when i restart browser it doesn't update it create a new session in database.

Comment: Perhaps the config option for `expire_on_close` but @Seralize is the one who wrote the code.  They would know better.

Answer (score 1):

A point on style... In all languages, I've always considered the underscore prefix to indicate reserved words, constants etc (PHP uses it for $_SESSION, $_GET and so forth, which fits this convention).

So better to use a *trailing* underscore in your class members, if you must use one at all.